# SharePoint PowerShell list filter

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

hoping someone can guide on the code below:

```
*$CreatedDate = (Get-Date $CreatedDateTime)
$AddedDateTime = (Get-Date $CreatedDate.AddMinutes(190))
Write-Host "CD:" $CreatedDate
Write-Host "AD:" $AddedDateTime
$ItemsColl = $ReviewList.Items | where {($_['Created'] -ge $CreatedDate) -and ($_['Created'] -le $AddedDateTime)}*
```

this is suppose to return everything within a date range, i pass on created date, add 190 minutes to that date, and the return should be everything from a workflow task list that was created as a task.

this does bring some but is missing most of the items in the list, i was hoping for an opinion to see if there is any obvious mistakes or maybe a new way of doing this.

Thanks in advance

---

ok so here is the scenario, when someone sends a document for approval, this creates a new version of document (uk Time), then a task is created by system account (Swiss Time +1hr from uk). I have a function that exports all the metadata for each version of the document into a csv format. where i'm struggling is filtering the reviewer list where all the tasks for each reviewer are stored.

i have two functions in my script GetMetadata and GetReviews.

Get metadata gets all metadata for each versions of the document, where a status changes to review in progress it suggests that the document has gone for a review so therefore we have to look into reviews list to find this item and see who the review was and what the outcome is, however the document could have been reviews multiple times and therefore i need to pass in document name, and datetime of created to filter the list, but date and time of created in review is 1hr and so ahead.
Script:

```
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables
$WebURL="http://site"
$ModuleList = "Library With Versions"
$ReportFile = "D:\Migration\Test\CSV\ItemsForum.csv"
$ReviewList = "Review Tasks"

    # *********************************************
    #delete file if exists
    If (Test-Path $ReportFile)
    {
        Remove-Item $ReportFile
    }

    #Get the Web and List
    $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
    $ReviewList = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ReviewList)
    #Get reviewers from review list
    function GetReviews($DocumentName, $CreatedDateTime)
    {
        $CreatedDate = Get-Date $CreatedDateTime
        #add 80 minutes, this would be plus one hr to swiss time plus account for time it takes to create item
        $AddedCreatedList = Get-Date $CreatedDate.AddMinutes(80)

        #filter and get items where document name matches workflow related item (this works but it's missing a lot of items as er image)
        $ItemsColl = $ReviewList.Items | where {$_['WorkflowLink'] -match $DocumentName -and $_['Created'] -ge $CreatedDate -and $_['Created'] -le $AddedCreatedList}
        #$ItemsColl = $ReviewList.Items
        Write-Host "Item Count: " $ItemsColl.Count
        $itemIds = ""
        if($ItemsColl.Count -gt 0)
        {
            foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)
            {
                Write-Host $relatedItemUrl
                #$relatedItem = $relatedItemUrl -split ','
                #$rit = $relatedItem[1].Trim()
                $itemIds += $item.id
                $itemIds += ";"
            }

            Write-Host $itemIds
            $itemIds = $itemIds.TrimEnd(";")
        }
        return $itemIds
    }

        function GetMetadata{
        $List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ModuleList)
        #Check if list exists
        if($List -ne $null)
        {
            #Get all list items
            $ItemsColl = $List.Items | where {$_['Module'] -match $ModuleName}
                #add headings
            Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value "Item ID, Status, File Name + Version, Created, Review ID"

                #Loop through each item
                foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)
                {
                    if ($item['Module'])
                    {
                        #Write-Host  $item['Module'] 
                        ForEach($version in $item.Versions)
                        {

                            #Add version label to file in format: [Filename]_v[version#].[extension]
                            $filesplit = $version['Name'].split(".")
                            $fullname = $filesplit[0]
                            $fileext = $filesplit[1]
                            #$FullFileName = $fullname+"_v"+$version.VersionLabel+"."+$fileext   
                            $FullFileName ="V_"+$version.VersionLabel+" " + $version['Name']


                            #Get Modified By
                            $user = $version["Editor"]
                            $userObj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $user)
                            $modifiedBy = $userObj.User.DisplayName

                            #get and format modified date 
                            $ModifiedDate = ($version['Modified'] -as [datetime]).DateTime
                            $ModifiedDateF = Get-Date $ModifiedDate -format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
                            #Write-Host $ModifiedDateF

                            #get and format created date 
                            $CreatedDate = ($version.Created -as [datetime]).DateTime
                            $CreatedDateF = Get-Date $CreatedDate -format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"

                            $ReviwerID = ""
                            #get reviewers

                            #if status matches an item get review list id
                            if($version['WFStatus'] -eq 'Review in progress'){
                                #pass document name and created 
                                $ReviwerID = GetReviews $version['Name'].TrimEnd('.docx') $version.Created

                            }
                            #add data 
                            $VersionData = "$($item.id),$($version['WFStatus']),$($FullFileName),$($CreatedDateF),$($ReviwerID)"


                            #Write to report
                            Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value $VersionData
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    GetMetadata

    Write-Host "Version history has been exported successfully!"
```

Output:
[Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y1b5.png)

Comment: Please add examples of what elements `$ReviewList.Items` contains directly to your question (don't respond in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script by SharePoint PowerShell, if your issue exists, provide more details for your script.

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$sourceWebURL = "http://sp:12001"
$sourceListName = "TestList"
$CreatedDate = Get-Date 
$AddedDateTime = Get-Date $CreatedDate.AddMinutes(190)
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$ReviewList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$ItemsColl = $ReviewList.Items | where {($_['Created'] -ge $CreatedDate.AddMinutes(-10)) -and ($_['Created'] -le $AddedDateTime)}
Write-Host "CD:" $CreatedDate.AddMinutes(-10)
Write-Host "AD:" $AddedDateTime
$ItemsColl | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_['ID']
    Write-Host $_['Title']
}
```

Update:

You could use PowerGUI editor to debug your script, the tool would help you find out most of logic issue.

[image]

Comment: added whole script and output, this should give you an idea of what i'm trying to do.